# How to bind ObjectListview header to an object?

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I have single ObjectListview which should show different models while user is switching some controls. So using Form designer is not an option to set headers/columns. I need to switch them dynamically.

I know I can do it using `AllColumns` described [here](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/faq.html#how-do-i-add-or-remove-a-column-programmatically), delete and add again. But my question is can I do it through some object, just like I feed data to the list view? Then I would have different columns object alongside with data object and would switch them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the cookbook then Number 29 is probably what you are after. http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#can-i-generate-the-whole-objectlistview-directly-from-my-model
(Below is taken from this source).

There is a `Generator` class, to which you can pass your model and it will automatically create the columns based on the public properties.

```
Generator.GenerateColumns(this.olv1, typeof(MyModelClass), true);
```

You can even enhance your model by using `OLVColumn` attributes.

```
public class MyClass {

    [OLVColumn(Width = 150)]
    public DateTime When { get; set; }

    [OLVColumn(DisplayIndex = 5, Width = 75, TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right)]
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    [OLVColumn("From", DisplayIndex=1, Width = 50, TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center)]
    public string FromCurrency { get; set; }

    [OLVColumn("To", DisplayIndex = 3, Width = 50, TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center)]
    public string ToCurrency { get; set; }

    [OLVColumn("Amount", DisplayIndex = 2, AspectToStringFormat = "{0:C}", Width = 75, TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right)]
    public decimal FromValue { get; set; }

    [OLVColumn("Amount", DisplayIndex = 4, AspectToStringFormat = "{0:C}", Width = 75, TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right)]
    public decimal ToValue { get; set; }

    [OLVColumn(IsVisible = false)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```